# JavaScript search function is also searching html code

Tags: javascript, search, accordion

I want to use html tags within answers  section but when I do the code is pulling through when using the search. I have little experience with JavaScript so any advice would be very helpful

JavaScript

```
$('h3.Topic').click(function () {
    $(this).next().toggle(300);
});
$('h4.Question').click(function () {
    $(this).next().toggle(300);
});
$('#ExpandAll').click(function () {
    $('#FAQ').children('div.TopicContents').show(300).children('div.Answer').show(300);
});
$('#CollapseAll').click(function () {
    $('#FAQ').children('div.TopicContents').hide(300).children('div.Answer').hide();
});
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function (a, i, m) {
    return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
$('#SearchFAQ').click(function () {
    $('#FAQ').children('div.TopicContents').hide().children('div.Answer').hide();
    if ($('#FAQSearch').val() != '') {
        $('div.Answer:Contains(' + $('#FAQSearch').val().toUpperCase() + ')').show().parent().show(300);
        try {
            $('.highlight').removeClass("highlight");
            $('div.Answer:Contains(' + $('#FAQSearch').val().toUpperCase() + ')').each(function () {
                $(this).html(
                    $(this).html().replace(
                        new RegExp($('#FAQSearch').val(), "ig"),
                        function (match) {
                            return '<span class="highlight">' + match + '</span>';
                        }
                    )
                )
            });
        } catch (err) {}
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: link to the code Im using : http://rthilton.com/Blog/Demos/FAQDemo.html

Comment: "the code is pulling through", What does that mean?

Comment: when I type in say p into the search and within the answer div I have used p tags the actually syntax will show.

Comment: Try with the following regex: `/(?:^|>)\s*(yourSearchTerm)\s*(?:<|$)/ig`

Comment: where in the code would I place this ?

Comment: Its okay I found where to put the code and it worked thanks

Comment: actually sorry it didn't totally work it removed the yellow highlights from the searched text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `new RegExp($('#FAQSearch').val(), "ig")` by `new RegExp('(' + $('#FAQSearch').val() + ')(?![^<]*>)', "ig")`.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/4PWRj/

```
var $searchArea = $('#search-area');

$('input').keyup(function () {
    var value = this.value.trim(), rx;

    $searchArea.find('.highlight').each(function () {
        this.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(this.textContent), this);
    });

    if (!value) return;

    rx = new RegExp('(' + this.value + ')(?![^<]*>)', "ig");

    $searchArea.html($searchArea.html().replace(rx, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>'));
});
```

Comment: sorry it didn't totally work it removed the yellow highlights from the searched text

Comment: @user3771581 I updated the answer and posted an example.